# json.loads not working in django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a  object(or string ? I am not sure..) in my mysql database, and I want to turn it back to python dictionary in views and then process it and then send back to html.

so here is my code in views.py:

```
def measure_detail(request, measurement_id):

        _ClickedPts = ClickedPts.objects.get(measurement=measurement_id)

        _ClickedPts = json.loads(_ClickedPts)

        return render(request, 'measurement_detail.html', {'measurement': _measurement, 'clicked_pts': _ClickedPts})
```

_clickedPts looks like this:

> {0: {u'loc': [1, 2], u'pts': [[456.45631334215614, 1155.23758883418], [1087.2590986710893, 1175.6156203824098]], u'imsize': (3264, 2448)}, 9: {u'loc': [1, 2], u'pts': [[838.4383679397915, 1183.738210969312], [1751.0879501479042, 1179.0747927841176]], u'imsize': (3264, 2448)}, 28: {u'loc': [1, 2], u'pts': [[1544.854017880959, 1041.081669022464], [2262.6099907645976, 1044.953878976804]], u'imsize': (3264, 2448)}, 14: {u'loc': [1, 2], u'pts': [[1122.5721676687076, 1211.5634319190933], [2053.740361759838, 1221.0344281491446]], u'imsize': (3264, 2448)}, 15: {u'loc': [1, 2], u'pts': [[1037.1904375418785, 1166.702956796377], [1959.451782586886, 1190.2974020603272]], u'imsize': (3264, 2448)}}

Comment: What's your DB? Where have you get from that 'looks like this'? When you perform a `.get()` query from Manager, you get an object instance of the `ClickedPts` class, not a string or dict or json, that's why you can not apply `.loads()` function.

Comment: What type is `_clickedPts`? _clickedPts-looks-like-this look like a python dictionary. But you cannot get python dictionaries from the django-db.

Comment: @Gocht  I used mysql, and I get the _clickedPts above from another general python file where I connect to my database and get it. If it is an instance, how should I change it to a python dictionary?

Comment: @Daniel I used Mysql. The string I have above is from another general python file where I connect to my database and get it.

Comment: Well, you have an object, I am not sure where did you get that dict as repr of a model, but you don't get that when you use Django's ORM. You can take a look over [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) Manager function to get you model object as a dict.

Comment: Thanks, .values() work @gocht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
test = ClickedPts.objects.values('pts')

test = test[0]['pts']

test = ast.literal_eval(test)

#print type(test)
#print test
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string isn't a proper JSON string, and actually looks like a Python JSON object. You would be better off using ast.literal_eval to convert this string to a Python JSON Object. Just call ast.literal_val(_ClickedPts) instead of json.loads(_ClickedPts) to get what you want.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval